# Declared closure result '?' is incompatible with contextual type ''

Tags: swift, firebase

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Declared closure result 'InstockProduct?' is incompatible with contextual type 'InstockProduct'

```
class Database {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var products = [InstockProduct]()

    func getProductsInCollection(collection: String, handler: @escaping ([InstockProduct]) -> Void) {
        db.collection("/products/instock/\(collection)").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, err in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else{
                print("No document")
                handler([])
                return
            }
            self.products = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> InstockProduct in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: InstockProduct.self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr7zi.png)

Comment: Please share code, not images of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers.

Comment: @jnpdx sry, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `products` declared as `[InstockProduct]` (with non-optionals).

Also, in your closure, you have a return type specified as `InstockProduct` (again, non-optional).

But, in your return statement, you return an optional when you do this:

```
return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: InstockProduct.self)
```

Given that the `try` could fail, I'd change your code to return an optional and then use `compactMap` to remove those optionals from the final array:

```
self.products = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> InstockProduct? in
    return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: InstockProduct.self)
}
```